# How to pass parameters to a function within an Angular directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, scope

Within an [AngularJS directive](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive), I trigger a callback function that needs access to a directive-level object that has been injected.

I am using a KendoUI template function for this, however I think this is more an issue about scope than the function.

Directive:

```
app.directive('projectEditorGrid', function (dataSourceFactory) {

    var dataSourceFactory = new dataSourceFactory("/odata/ProjectEditor");

    return {
        link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            $element.kendoGrid({
                dataSource: dataSourceFactory.projects(),
                pageable: true,
                height: 400,
                toolbar: ["create"],
                columns: [
                            { field: "WebsiteName", editable: true, width: 190, title: "Project Name", validation: { required: { message: "Project name is required" } } },
                            { field: "WebsiteNotes", title: "Project Notes" },
                            { field: "WebsiteGUID", title: "Project API ID", editable: false },
                            { field: "DefaultContentType", title: "Default Content Type", width: "160px", editor: defaultContentTypeDropDownEditor, template: "#=ContentTypes.Descriptions#" },
                            { command: ["edit", "destroy"] }
                ],
                editable: "inline"
            });

            function defaultContentTypeDropDownEditor(container, options) {
                console.log(container + " : " + options);
                var dataSourcFactory = dataSourceFactory("/odata/ContentType");
                var dsContentTypes = dataSourceFactory.contentTypes();  // returns a kendo.data.DataSource() object

                $('<input required data-text-field="Description" data-value-field="ContentTypeId" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>')
                    .appendTo(container)
                    .kendoDropDownList({
                        autoBind: false,
                        dataSource: dataSourceFactory.contentTypes()
                    }); // kendoDropDownList
            }
        }
    }
});
```

`dataSourceFactory` is injected into the directive and successfully used to display the data.

When a row edit is triggered, `defaultContentTypeDropDownEditor` is called with its default parameters, `container, options`.   If I could pass the `dataSourceFactory` to this function I'd be set, but not clear on how to accomplish this from the activating call.

`options`:

```
Object {field: "DefaultContentType", editor: function, model: n.extend.o}
editor: function defaultContentTypeDropDownEditor(container, options) {
field: "DefaultContentType"
model: n.extend.o
__proto__: Object
```

`container`:

```
[<td role=​"gridcell" data-container-for=​"DefaultContentType">​</td>​]
```

As you can see, `dataSourceFactory` is visible at the function level (injected into the directive), however is not accessible from within the `defaultContentTypeDropDownEditor`.  Can someone please explain how to accomplish this?

Comment: You have a `var dataSourcFactory` (missing `e`). Is that a typo? If yes, and the actual name of the var is `dataSourceFactory`, it *hides* the `dataSourceFactory` from the outer scope. Try renaming it to something meaningful but different.

Comment: Your comment naming and hiding scope lead me to the answer, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The injected object is `dataSourceFactory`.  By renaming the initial initialization to `dataSourceFactory1` and the function callback's use of it to `dataSourceFactory2`, I was able to get this  working.

Thanks to Nikos for pointing me in the right direction.